PWA Flickers when invoking SMS and dialog appears
I have a progressive web app (PWA) that provides canned text for quit texting to a phone number and uses the phone's SMS app to eventually send the text (https://www.gallaware.com/qt") On Android, it works fine when in the browser - either Chrome or Firefox. When the user clicks "Send text message...", in Firefox a dialog appears, "Open in another app", and asks if the user wants to Cancel or Open. This works just fine.
When it is dropped onto the Home page from Firefox, and the users clicks the "Send text message...", the same dialog causes flickering making it difficult to click "Open". I know many may call this an edge case since few might use Firefox on a phone, but I'm worried that there is an underlying issue that I'm missing, and Chrome is not actually showing, that should be correct.
There is nothing special about the app, its just a single simple page with a little Javascript.

The original code invokes the SMS with:
window.open('sms:1234567890&body=textGoesHere', '_blank');
Reading some other SO articles, I removed the '_blank', so the call is:
window.open('sms:1234567890&body=textGoesHere');
but the same issue still occurs.
